Apache Superset Dashboard Export Excel
We can download only one of the charts in the Apache Supersette dashboard in excel format. But I want to download all charts in a single excel file if there is more than one chart on the dashboard. In short, I want to export the dashboard as excel.
Single Chart Export Options
I want to be able to download the entire dashboard as excel from here.
I tried to solve this problem on the source code side, but I couldn't solve it.
